# Publishing bulk of messages using NService Bus

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

I want to publish bulk of messages using NServiceBus.
I found one overloaded Publish method which takes list of messages as a parameter.
When I tried using it, it shows the following error:

```
  var message= new Message
                    {                           
                        Id = id,
                        Timestamp = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local),
                        PublishingStartTimestamp = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local)

                    };

                    bus.Publish(new[] { message, message});
```

Error: 'NServiceBus.IBus.Publish(params T[])' is obsolete: 'Removed to reduce complexity and API confusion. See https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus/issues/1346 for more information. Will be removed in version 5.0.0.'

What is an alternative to publish bulk of messages.
**My task is to publish 600 events per second.**

Comment: If this being done within a handler or saga, so within a incoming message context?

Comment: Please contact us regarding your use case. We are very interested in discussing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NServicebus supports asynchronous publishing of messages: https://particular.net/blog/async-await-its-time

Assuming you are outside the receiving message context you can collect all the publish Tasks in a list of Tasks and then have the Tasks run async with WhenAll for instance.

Also make sure you are not reaching the limit of max messages per sec of azure service bus.

**Update**
See Ramon Smit's answer for a full answer.

Comment: HI, I am not able to find any method named as PublishAsync. I have latest version of NService Bus. Can you please help me

Comment: With NSB 6 Publish is async https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/5to6/async-suffix

Comment: You made my day. Thanks buddy!

Comment: Even though V6 is async, messages will only be pushed to the transport after after all handlers and sagas have been invoked.

Comment: @Ramon Could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan please see my response.

Comment: @RamonSmits Ah yeah, I've assumed too much. I've assumed outside of a receiving message context. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

### High volume

I'm not sure what your use case is. 600 msg/s translates to almost 52 million message per day for a single endpoint if this is a consistent flow of messages.

### Use case

We would be interested in your use case and we can discuss this publicly in our google groups

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware

We can also do this privately by contacting us at support@particular.net

### Receive as a single or individual message

If you send those 600 messages, do you want to treat them as a single message at the receiving end? The reason I ask is that's what the API in the question does. It creates a single envelope that contains all those messages. On the transport, you would see a single physical message. On the receiving end, all messages would be processed as a single receive operation.

If this is the behavior you want, you must create a message that contains a collection (array/list) and just put all those message fragments in it.

The good thing about this strategy is that you have made the behavior more explicit in the contract.

```
var message = new ParentMessage();
for(int i=0;i<600;i++) message.Children.Add(new ChildFragment());
Bus.Publish(message);
```

### Transport message size limitations

Azure Service Bus message can at most be 256KB on the standard tier and 1MB on the premium tier. The previous solution to have a single large message would probably not work if the fragments contain a lot of data.

### Receiving context

In your question, it is unclear if you are sending these message in the context of a receiving message or outside of a receiving context. The behavior is different for each.

Within an incoming message context, sends are buffered. Outside an incoming message context, messages are directly pushed to the transport.

### Batched dispatch

You are using Azure Service Bus in either NServiceBus V5 or V6 sends are buffered by default. If you do a publish/send in a handler/saga the message is not pushed to the transport immediately.

The reason for this behavior is to prevent 'ghost' messages. Imagine you send a message, after that you create a second message and during mapping, a null reference exception occurs. Did or didn't you want that first message to have already been pushed to the transport? Probably not, and that is the default behavior.

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/batched-dispatch

For Azure Service Bus this behavior is also present in V5 by performing a transaction scope enlistment. If you do not want this behavior in V5, then disable usage of transaction scopes by disabling distributed transactions.

### Async

In V6 the API is async, meaning you could do something like:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for(int i=0;i<600;i++) tasks.Add(context.Publish(new MyEvent()));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);;
```

Due to buffered sends this does not really make a huge difference unless the creation of the message is performing IO.

If you are doing this outside of a receiving message context then it DOES improve performance.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for(int i=0;i<600;i++) tasks.Add(messageSession.Publish(new MyEvent()));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);;
```

This is because messages will be pushed to the transport immediately and concurrently.

### Immediate dispatch

If you explicitly do not want the buffering of messages, then you can use immediate dispatch. The following is a V6 sample.

```
var options = new SendOptions();
options.RequireImmediateDispatch();
var message = new MyMessage();
await context.Send(message, options).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/send-a-message#dispatching-a-message-immediately

### Performance

The API that you use in the description is either NServiceBus V5 or earlier. In V6 Azure Service Bus performance has improved considerably.

There are a lot of variables that can be tweaked to improve performance.

- https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-service-bus/performance-tuning

It should not be a problem at all to send/receive thousands of messages per second for a single endpoint instance in V6.

Comment: Hi we need this tool to just perform load testing of our worker role. We generate 600 msg/sec for 10 minutes and test behavior of API. Thanks for the great explanation

Comment: @mangeshKulkarni If you want to build a client for load testing then please take a look at the following project https://github.com/Particular/EndToEnd/tree/master/src/PerformanceTests

For example, https://github.com/Particular/EndToEnd/blob/master/src/PerformanceTests/Common/Scenarios/BaseRunner.cs#L95-L140

this seeds data and might help you push data to a queue as fast as possible. Also look at the various transport configurations to tweak the transport for optimal performance.

Comment: @RamonSmits I took the liberty of editing `Childs` to `Children`.